# What is the behavior of this family of iterative sequences?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations, recursion

Consider a sequence $a_k(n)$, where $a_k(1) = 1$, and $a_k(n) = a_k(a_k(n-1) \pmod {n-1}) + k$ for integer $k > 1$.

For the first few $k$, the sequence quickly stabilizes, ending in an infinite repeating string of numbers, almost always of period $1$.

I'm I haven't proved whether the sequence starts infinitely repeating for all $k$, though, and I don't know if the length of time it takes to stabilize grows quickly with $k$, or how quickly it grows.

The first few sequences are as follows:

$a_2(n) = 1,3,3,5,3,5,5,5,5,5...$ Stabilizing by $6$ steps.

$a_3(n) = 1,4,7,4,7,7,4,7,7,7,7,7...$ Stabilizing by $8$ steps.

$a_4(n) = 1,5,5,9,5,9,9,9,5,9,9,9,9,9...$ Stabilizing by $10$ steps.

$a_5(n) = 1,6,11,11,16,6,11,16,21,16,11,16,16,16,11,16,21,16,21,11,16,21,21,21,...$ Stabilizing by $22$ steps.

---

A second related sequence, $b_k(n)$, is defined with iterated multiplication by k instead of addition. $b_k(1)=1$, and $b_k(n) = k*b_k(b_k(n-1) \pmod {n-1})$.

The sequences for $ k=1, 2, 3$ stabilize quickly into a repeating pattern, but I have no idea whether or not the sequence stabilizes for any other $k$.

$b_2(n) = 1,2,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,4...$ Stabilizing by $5$ steps.

b_3(n) = $1,3,3,9,3,9,9,9,3,9,9,9,9,9...$ Stabilizing by $10$ steps.

Does this sequence stabilize for $k=4$ or greater?

Comment: Two things: (1) TeX is your friend!  (2) When you say 'mod', what residue classes are you using? In particular, the usual definitions of 'mod $n$' take the residue classes as $0\ldots (n-1)$, which should lead to $a_k(2)=({a_k(1)\bmod 1})+k = k$ since $i\bmod1=0$ for all $i$, whereas you have it as $k+1$...

Comment: This is because the sequence stabilizes when the length of the sequence is greater than any element of itself. After this point, a(a(n-1)) mod (n-1) is equal to a(a(n-1), and does not change with the length of the sequence.

Comment: These sequences are not here: https://oeis.org/. You can submit them to the OEIS if you want: https://oeis.org/Submit.html

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE Industrium! Please consult this link on how to format questions and answers: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Steven: Sorry for not clarifying, I think I'm using the residue class {1,2,3,4,...n}. In this case, (n mod n) is n. I'm not very well versed in the notation, because math is mainly a hobby for me at this point.